# How to hold shadow in recyclerview while scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using shadow library in horizontal recyclerview and whenever i scroll left or right shadow will disappears

```
<com.gigamole.library.ShadowLayout
            android:id="@+id/go_shadow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:sl_shadow_angle="90"
            app:sl_shadow_color="@color/shadow_color"
            app:sl_shadow_distance="10dp"
            app:sl_shadow_radius="10dp"
            app:sl_shadowed="true"
            >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downloadIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/go_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/go_height"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_go_manual" />
        </com.gigamole.library.ShadowLayout>
```

For reference
[shadow library](https://github.com/Devlight/ShadowLayout)

[pic before scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiJ3r.png)

[pic after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS4NI.png)

Comment: please clarify your question more and explain what you have tried and what you're struggling with. post the code you're using

Comment: post your code in your question

Comment: For shadow Use Cardview and set elevation property for items in recyclerview

Comment: I have tried but still same issue

Answer (score 2):

if you want a shadow effect for an image view. Then ad these lines of code for your image view:

```
    android:elevation="25dp"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds"
```

if you want a shadow effect for Card view. Then ad these lines of code for your Card view:

```
app:cardElevation="15dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
```